# sklearn - How to retrieve variables (classification parameters) from LinearSVC model

Tags: scikit-learn

sklearn's svm LinearSVC uses the following model:

LinearSVC: `1/2||[w b]||^2 + C SUM xi_i`

I have been looking through the documentation and can't find any way to find these values. Specifically the w vector, b and C values. The LinearSVC class seems to have a `get_params` method but none of the returned parameters match up to the classification parameters.

Does anyone have any experience retrieving these values? Is it even possible with sklearn's LinearSVC?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fit the model first and then you can access them as attributes of your estimator.

- **w** = `coef_`
- b = `intercept_`

C = `C` is a hyperparameter set by you before fitting and note that **the higher the less regularization**